# how to set all inputs as $touched without submit button AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a directive that validates inputs inside a form based on their `$valid` and `$untouched` properties - if the input was "touched" it checks for validation and colors the font and border in red/green accordingly, if the input wasn't "touched" it won't do anything.

I'm using ngBootBox's custom dialog so i don't have the `type="submit"` kind of button for submitting the form, I'm using the callback function of the "Create" button in order to pass/save the data.

My problem is that when I click the "create" button and the form is not "valid" because some of the fields are empty - my inputs are still "untouched" so the `$watch` function isn't being called.
Any solutions? Is there a way to do something like this:
`$scope.createProjectForm.$setTouched(true);` that will make all child inputs of that form to get that value?

I also tried that and it didn't work:

```
angular.forEach($scope.createProjectForm, function(field){
   field.$setTouched(true);
});
```

this is my validation directive:

```
angular.module('mean.theme').directive("inputValidation", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, inputElement, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            var $icon = $('<i class="fa"></i>');
            inputElement.before($icon);
            scope.$watchGroup([
                function(){
                    return ngModelCtrl.$untouched;
                },
                function(){
                    return ngModelCtrl.$valid;
                }
            ], function(Paramaters){
                console.log(scope);

                if(!Paramaters[0]) {
                    if (Paramaters[1]) {
                        inputElement.switchClass('validation-warning-border','validation-success-border',50)
                        inputElement.prev().switchClass('fa-warning validation-warning-font' , 'fa-check validation-success-font',50);
                    } else {
                        inputElement.switchClass('validation-success-border','validation-warning-border',50)
                        inputElement.prev().switchClass('fa-check validation-success-font','fa-warning validation-warning-font',50)
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and this is part of my controller code:

```
    $scope.create = function () {
        var options = {
            title: 'Create',
            templateUrl: 'project.html',
            scope: $scope,
            buttons: {
                warning: {
                    label: "Cancel",
                    className: "btn-link",
                    callback: function () {
                    }
                },
                success: {
                    label: "Create",
                    className: "green",
                    callback: function () {
                        if ($scope.createProjectForm.$valid){
                            $scope.createProject(template);
                        } else {
                            $scope.project.createButtonClicked = true;
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        $ngBootbox.customDialog(options);
    };
```

and this is part of my HTML code:

```
<form role="form" name="createProjectForm">
    <label>
        Name Your Project
    </label>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="project.name"
               ng-model="project.name" required="required" class="form control" input-validation/>
    </div>
    <label>
        Name Your Project
    </label>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="project.title"
               ng-model="project.title" required="required" class="form control" input-validation/>
    </div>
</form>
```

- **EDIT:**

I found what i needed, easier and shorter way to do it:

It is possible to set manually:
`$scope.createProjectForm.$setSubmitted()` to `true`

and then make the children(inputs) `$watch` for this change as well:

```
scope.$watchGroup([
            function(){
                return ngModelCtrl.$untouched;
            },
            function(){
                return ngModelCtrl.$valid;
            },
            function(){
                return ngModelCtrl.$$parentForm.$submitted;
            }
        ], function(Paramaters){
         // code here
        }
```

Comment: Did you try: $setTouched() without 'true'?

Comment: form.control.markAllAsTouched()

Comment: @Pankwood form.control does not exist. Totally wrong comment...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could follow a format similar to this:

```
if ($scope.form.$invalid) {
    angular.forEach($scope.form.$error, function (field) {
        angular.forEach(field, function(errorField){
            errorField.$setTouched();
        });
    });
}
```

See '$setTouched': https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Comment: it worked. thanks!
by the way, is there a way to do it without iterating each input with angular forEach function? is there a way to use my existing $watch function in order to that? like for an example, when the button is clicked - set one of my form's parameters -  and make the inputs $watch function watch the change? is there something similar to that with less code and less iterating?

Comment: watch out for nested ng-form items

Answer (score 2):

For nested forms:

```
function setFormTouched(form) {
        // Check if the form/property has the $setSubmitted method
        if (form.hasOwnProperty('$submitted')) {
            // Iterate through each of the required error properties
            angular.forEach(form.$error, function (errorType) {
                // Iterate through each error type
                angular.forEach(errorType, function (prop) {
                    // Check if the property has the $setTouched method
                    if (prop.hasOwnProperty('$touched')) prop.$setTouched();
                    // Recursive call to handle nested forms
                    setFormTouched(prop);
                });

            });
        }
    }
```

Solution is based on [codepen](http://codepen.io/patrickmarabeas/pen/xGLLLW) by Patrick Marabeas But I had to edit the original code because `hasOwnProperty` didn't work for functions defined in prototype.
For example:

```
if(prop.hasOwnProperty('$setTouched'))
```

Always returned false.

**EDIT:**
What I originally needed was a way to make it easier for the user to find errors in nested tabs. This was the final working scope function used for disabling/enabling submit button and error message:

```
$scope.isFormValid = function (topLevelForm) {
        if (topLevelForm.$valid) {
            return true;
        }

        // Form not valid, triggering fields to make it easier to find errors
        setFormTouched(topLevelForm);

        function setFormTouched(form) {
            // Check if the form/property has the $setSubmitted method
            if (form.hasOwnProperty('$submitted')) {
                // Iterate through each of the required error properties
                angular.forEach(form.$error, function (errorType) {
                    // Iterate through each error type
                    angular.forEach(errorType, function (prop) {
                        // Check if the property has the $setTouched method
                        if (prop.hasOwnProperty('$touched')) prop.$setTouched();
                        // Recursive call to handle nested forms
                        setFormTouched(prop);
                    });

                });
            }
        }
        return false;
    };
```